# Modx Unable to login to manager area

Tags: modx

I've just transferred a modx site for a client over to fasthosts - got the site setup working fine but when logging into the backend I'm getting Incorrect Username / Password.

I know that the credentials are correct.

Any ideas?

Using 1.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it!

It seems to create all site content including paths and sessions within files on server... So obviously I'd ftp from old host to new host, put live expected to work which front end did because it doesn't use session data but then the backend had it's knickers in a twist

I setup a new installation with a db prefix test_ - once site was installed changed db parameters then cleared site cache, uploaded new template files etc.

Cheers

Shane

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of similar issues before when people migrate a site to a shared host. Does this [solution](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php/topic,35112.msg212848.html#msg212848) help?

Comment: I think it would help, unfortunatley Fasthosts don't allow you to change php_value within .htaccess Already read that post... Thanks Anyway